# Prevent checkbox from bubbling events to the parent table row

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Below is my ember js code for data table , when user select on the table row its navigate to different page "goToMerchantsManage", that should not happen when user clicks on the check box. How can i skip the navigation only for the check box.

```
> {{#each this.model.data as |entity|}}
>             <tr {{action "goToMerchantsManage" entity}}>

>               **<td><input type="checkbox"  > </td>**

>               {{#if (get (find-by 'propertyName' 'id' this.columns) 'active')}}
>                 <td>{{entity.id}} </td>
>               {{/if}}
>               {{#if (get (find-by 'propertyName' 'merchant.mid' this.columns) 'active')}}
>                 <td>
>                   <div class="text-nowrap d-flex flex-wrap">
>                     {{#each entity.merchant.mids as |mpa_mid|}}
>                       {{generic/mpa-mid-label mpa_mid=mpa_mid}}
>                     {{/each}}
>                   </div>
>                 </td>
>               {{/if}}
>               {{#if (get (find-by 'propertyName' 'contactInfo.companyName' this.columns) 'active')}}
>                 <td> {{text-highlight entity.contactInfo.companyName query=this.searchQuery}} </td>
>               {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use the [built-in ember checkbox](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.18.0/components/built-in-components/#toc_checkboxes)

```
<Input
  @id="admin-checkbox"
  @type="checkbox"
  @checked={{this.isAdmin}}
/>
```

then in order to solve your problem you just need to stop the event propagation:

```
<Input
  @id="admin-checkbox"
  @type="checkbox"
  @checked={{this.isAdmin}}
  {{on "click" (stop-propagation)}}
/>
```

(note that you can pass an action to the `stop-propagation` depending on your needs. And don't forget to [install](https://github.com/buschtoens/ember-event-helpers) `ember-event-helper`